# How to get current controller for a URL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code to highlight currently active menu tab with Twitter Bootstrap:

```
  def nav_link_to(link_text, link_path, options = nil)
    class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''

    content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
      link_to link_text, link_path, options
    end
  end
```

This of course makes the link active, only if the given link IS the current page. 
How can I change this function, such that it would return 'active' for any links below current controller? 
In other words, for all actions for Posts controller, the links would be active?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `controller_name` to get the name of the current controller.

Comment: Yes, but the question was - how do I check that a link or URL belongs to some controller - this is what the code is about.

Comment: You don't. But you can just use it manually: `link_to 'posts', posts_path, :class => params[:controller] == 'posts' ? 'active' : ''`

Comment: You could, like, regex it... `:class => path =~ params[:controller] ? 'active' : ''`... but that's seems gross to me.

Comment: Guides recommend to use `controller_name` instead of `params[:controller]`.

Comment: using controller_name and/or action_name are the usual way to solve this problem

Comment: @rfunduk this could work in most cases imho, but sometimes :root is pointing to Home, and then this isn't a good case, please consider (nav_link_to 'Home', root_path) - we geet '/' for the second parameter, which doesn't have any controller name, but it does belong to Home controller!

Comment: @rfunduk i will accept your answer, but I'd like to know, maybe someone knows the "Rails" way to achieve this cleanly.

Comment: @systho it isn't usual. this won't work in some cases. please read my comment to rfunduk

Comment: I don't know for the Rails way but the REST way is to use a redirect on your root path instead of defining what controller/action pair should handle the '/' request

maybe the current_url? methods can help, too http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Comment: I just added 'controller' as 3rd parameter to this function, and using controller_name I'm setting {class_name = (controller_name == controller) ? 'active' : ''}. This works as expected. One thing that confused me in current_page? function -- current_page?(:controller => 'library') will return true only to one and only one URL, and not for all of the actions that belong to this controller. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7):

This could be solved with:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(link_path)[:controller]
```

Answer (score 5):

`params[:controller]` returns controller name with its namespace.

If you want to get controller name only you should use `controller.controller_name`.

```
class Admin::Posts; end

# from the view
params[:controller] 
=> 'admin/posts'

controller.controller_name
=> 'posts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I read this correctly, but you shouldn't use a get param to see the current controller.

Have you tried using `request.path` ? In other words, check if any of the links below include 'request.path' in their path...